# How to put pointer to char into another pointer to char

Tags: c, pointers, char

I want to put pointer `char* name` into `char* path`. I'm getting value of **name** from scanf. Is it possible?

```
char* path = "/home/user/Desktop/name.jpg";
```

I know it's wrong but i want this to work in that way

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Saying `path = name` is not, in general, wrong, and does what you ask for.

Comment: Be careful here - the issue is string handling in C is not obvious.  A char * is just a pointer to the first character in the string; somehow, there needs to be memory allocated to the thing at which it points.  strdup() is a safe way to copy an existing string.  Scanf() is dangerous for reading into a string buffer as it can easily overflow the target buffer unless the format string limits the input properly.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to copy the string if it won't be modified; path = name works perfectly well in that case.

Comment: You must remember to `free` `result`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you mean that you have:

```
char *name = "fred";
char *format = "/home/user/Desktop/name.jpg";
```

And you'd like to take that and then *do something* such that you have as a result:

```
char *result = "/home/user/Desktop/fred.jpg";
```

To do this, you need to allocate some memory (or allocate enough somewhere else), and then use `sprintf()` or `snprintf()`:

```
char *name   = "fred";
char *format = "/home/user/Desktop/%s.jpg";

char *result = malloc(strlen(format) - 2 + strlen(name) + 1);
sprintf(result, format, name);

printf("%s\n", result); // Output is "/home/user/Desktop/fred.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the string using a couple functions. The first thing that comes to mind is `memcpy`

```
char* name = "/home/user/Desktop/name.jpg"; 
char* path;

size_t len = strlen(name);
path = malloc(len + 1); /* plus 1 for the null terminator */

if(path == NULL) exit(1);

memcpy(path, name, 1 + len);

/* do whatever */

free(path);
```